# IF statement with OR condition does not work for a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement

I want to add new column to my dataframe that only has two values ,1 and 0. 1 if either of the x, y, and z columns have an instance of 1, and 0 otherwise. For instance, with this rule, all but rows 6 and 9 have new column value as 1. The problem is that my `if` statement does not work, and it seems that I used the `or` condition correctly becasue when I extract the `or` part and run it on a specific row of my dataframe, it works fine. Hence, I think that I made some mistakes in iteration process of `for` loop.

I would appreciate if someone could help me on this.

```
set.seed(1)
x <- sample(1:3, 10, replace = TRUE)
y <- sample(1:3, 10, replace = TRUE)
z <- sample(1:3, 10, replace = TRUE)
df <- data.frame(x,y,z)

for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
  if ((df$x[i] == 1)== TRUE | (df$y[i] == 1) == TRUE | (df$z[i] == 1) == TRUE){
    df$new <- 1
  }
  else{
    df$new <- 0
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need indices on your `new`-variable. Note though that there are faster ways to achieve this end using the `apply`-family instead of a loop (I am sure other's will post these).

```r
for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
  if ((df$x[i] == 1) | (df$y[i] == 1) | (df$z[i] == 1)){
    df$new[i] <- 1
  }
  else{
    df$new[i] <- 0
  }
}
```

We could even shorten it to, converting the logical to numeric:

```r
for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
  df$new[i] <- +((df$x[i] == 1) | (df$y[i] == 1) | (df$z[i] == 1))
}
```

Output:

```
df
   x y z new
1  1 3 3   1
2  3 1 1   1
3  1 1 1   1
4  2 1 1   1
5  1 2 1   1
6  3 2 2   0
7  3 2 1   1
8  2 2 1   1
9  2 3 2   0
10 3 1 2   1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a new variable based on if any of the columns `x`, `y`, `z` have a value of 1, you don't need a `for` loop. One option in base R is:

```
df$new <- apply(df, 1, function(x) +any(x == 1))

#    x y z new
# 1  1 3 3   1
# 2  3 1 1   1
# 3  1 1 1   1
# 4  2 1 1   1
# 5  1 2 1   1
# 6  3 2 2   0
# 7  3 2 1   1
# 8  2 2 1   1
# 9  2 3 2   0
# 10 3 1 2   1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)

df[, new := +(rowSums(.SD == 1) >= 1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterating through a loop is slow. The base `ifelse()` function is vectorized and a fast solution can be coded:

```
df$new4 <- ifelse(df$x == 1 | df$y == 1 | df$z == 1, 1, 0)
```

A code golf answer (assumes df only has three columns, else use  `df[,1:3]`

```
df$new5 <- +(rowSums(df==1)>0)
```

My fastest submission

```
df$new6 <- +(df$x == 1 | df$y == 1 | df$z == 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

this is the typical case for `dplyr::if_any`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
    mutate(new = +if_any(x:z, ~.x ==1))

   x y z new
1  1 3 3   1
2  3 1 1   1
3  1 1 1   1
4  2 1 1   1
5  1 2 1   1
6  3 2 2   0
7  3 2 1   1
8  2 2 1   1
9  2 3 2   0
10 3 1 2   1
```